# R/mgcv: How do you interpret the 'fixed effects' for multivariate te() tensor products in the 'lme' part of a gamm model in R?

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model, mgcv, tensor

When fitting a 'gamm' model in the R package `mgcv`, and using a te() tensor product of three variables, the lme part of the model reports seven fixed effects, from 'Fx1' to 'Fx7', with coefficients and standard errors.

How should one interpret those coefficients?

example:

```
library(mgcv)
dat <- gamSim(1, n = 200, scale = 2)
b <- gamm(y ~ te(x0, x1, x2), data = dat)
summary(b$lme)
```

produces:

```
...
                      Value Std.Error  DF  t-value p-value
X(Intercept)       7.967688  0.151562 192 52.57042  0.0000
Xte(x0,x1,x2)Fx1 -11.272537  3.361371 192 -3.35355  0.0010
Xte(x0,x1,x2)Fx2  -5.423052  4.190418 192 -1.29416  0.1972
Xte(x0,x1,x2)Fx3  -0.203082  3.594615 192 -0.05650  0.9550
Xte(x0,x1,x2)Fx4  -6.921183  2.853750 192 -2.42529  0.0162
Xte(x0,x1,x2)Fx5  14.069427  3.367979 192  4.17741  0.0000
Xte(x0,x1,x2)Fx6 -16.363401  3.427253 192 -4.77449  0.0000
Xte(x0,x1,x2)Fx7  -8.381191  2.955847 192 -2.83546  0.0051
```

I suppose that:

- Xte(x0,x1,x2)Fx1 is the slope of the first linear basis function, in x0
- Xte(x0,x1,x2)Fx2 is the slope of the second linear basis function, in x1
- Xte(x0,x1,x2)Fx3 is the slope of the third linear basis function, in x2
- Xte(x0,x1,x2)Fx4 is the slope of the fourth linear basis function, in x0:x1
- Xte(x0,x1,x2)Fx5 is the slope of the fifth linear basis function, in x0:x2
- Xte(x0,x1,x2)Fx6 is the slope of the sixth linear basis function, in x1:x2
- Xte(x0,x1,x2)Fx7 is the slope of the seventh linear basis function, in x0:x1:x2

Is this correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, these fixed effect terms relate to the unpenalized functions in the basis (i.e. those functions in the null space). Note that what is in the null space entirely depends on the order of derivative-based penalty used; the default is `m = 2` so only linear/planar functions are unpenalised, but if you change this — or alter whether the function's basis even has a null space (via `m = c(2, 0)` say) — you'll get different basis functions in the null space and hence fewer/additional functions depending on settings.

There isn't a simple interpretation for these basis functions; that they're displayed in the fixed effects when you fit the model via `lme()` or `(g)lmer()` is just a side effect of the way the model has to be represented when using mixed effects software. If you were to refit the model using random effect smooth terms with `gam()` you wouldn't see this decomposition of penalized and unpenalized basis functions. You would see just the fitted smooths and you would just plot the resulting estimated function.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response Gavin. I have another doubt derived from your answer: Does the p-value of a basis function indicate whether a factor has a significant effect on the response variable? If we fit the model `gamm(y ~ s(x0) + s(x1), data = dat)` and `Xs(x0)Fx1` has a p-value of 0.36, can we say that the factor `x0` is not related to `y` and therefore should be removed from the model? Thank you again

Comment: No, you can't interpret it that way, Look at the model you fitted; it is basically two functions $f_1(x_0)$ and $f_2(x_1)$. You should do inference on those *functions*, not the individual basis functions that happen to be used to represent $f_1$ and $f_2$ in the model. In the same way that if you fitted `lm(y ~ poly(x0, 4))` you wouldn't remove the terms associated with $x_0^3$ just because it had a large p-value. You would be interested in the fit of the 4-th order polynomial over a 3-rd order one, say via a LRT.